# How to make media queries switch stylesheets

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following and I want it to switch what stylesheet is used, but the last stylesheet defined is being used, the media query is not working.
Do I need to do something in addition to what I am doing?

```
<!-- iPhone -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 320px)"
                                              href="/frontend/stylesheets/iPhone.css"/>

<!-- samsung -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
                                              href="/frontend/stylesheets/samsung.css"/>

<!-- iPad -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 768px)"
                                              href="/frontend/stylesheets/iPad.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of CSS [Specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and because your iPad media query is actually always going to be true (since the screen width on mobiles is always less than 768px). So it will override the rules/selectors you have in your other stylesheets.

You can try reordering you stylesheets the other way around (ie iPad lists first), but i would recommend you specify more explicit media queries to achieve what you want. Have a look at adding a `min-device-width` clause to your querys.

You can see an advanced example here:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/